# Calling a numpy function in Cython really slows things down

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, cython, probability

I'm trying to call `np.random.choice`, without replacement, row-by-row in a 2-D numpy array. I'm using Cython to get a speed boost.  The code is only running a factor of 3 faster than a pure-python implementation, which is not a great result.  The bottleneck is the numpy function call itself.  When I comment it out, and just supply a static result of, say `[3, 2, 1, 0]` to each row, I get a factor of 1000 speedup (of course then it's not doing much of anything :)

My question: is there something I'm doing wrong in calling the numpy function that's causing it to go super slow?  In theory it's C talking to C, so it should be fast.  I looked at the compiled code, and the call to the numpy function looks complex, with statements like `__Pyx_GOTREF` and `__Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr` that lead me to believe it's using pure python in the process (bad!!).

My code:

```
# tag: numpy

import numpy as np

# compile-time info for numpy
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()

# array dtypes
W_DTYPE = np.float
C_DTYPE = np.int

cdef int NUM_SELECTIONS = 4  # FIXME should be function kwarg

#compile-time dtypes
ctypedef np.float_t W_DTYPE_t
ctypedef np.int_t C_DTYPE_t


def allocate_choices(np.ndarray[W_DTYPE_t, ndim=2] round_weights,
                     np.ndarray[C_DTYPE_t, ndim=1] choice_labels):
    """
    For ea. row in  `round_weights` select NUM_SELECTIONS=4 items among
    corresponding `choice_labels`, without replacement, with corresponding
    probabilities in `round_weights`.

    Args:
        round_weights (np.ndarray): 2-d array of weights, w/
            size [n_rounds, n_choices]
        choice_labels (np.ndarray): 1-d array of choice labels,
            w/ size [n_choices]; choices must be *INTEGERS*

    Returns:
        choices (np.ndarray): selected items per round, w/ size
            [n_rounds, NUM_SELECTIONS]
    """

    assert round_weights.dtype == W_DTYPE
    assert choice_labels.dtype == C_DTYPE
    assert round_weights.shape[1] == choice_labels.shape[0]

    # initialize final choices array
    cdef int n_rows = round_weights.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray[C_DTYPE_t, ndim=2] choices = np.zeros([n_rows, NUM_SELECTIONS],
                                                          dtype=C_DTYPE)

    # Allocate choices, per round
    cdef int i, j
    cdef bint replace = False
    for i in range(n_rows):
        choices[i] = np.random.choice(choice_labels,
                                      NUM_SELECTIONS,
                                      replace,
                                      round_weights[i])

    return choices
```

Comment: What is `W_DTYPE_t` and `C_DTYPE_t`?

Comment: @JérômeRichard they're ctypedefed near the top

Comment: " In theory it's C talking to C, so it should be fast" - no. Not true. The main bit of Numpy that `cimport numpy` gives direct access to is just faster indexing of arrays. Numpy functions are called using the normal Python mechanism. They may ultimately be implemented in C, but that doesn't give a shortcut from Cython's point-of-view.

Answer (score 0):

Update on this, after chatting with some folks and examining the compiled code: @DavidW's comment above put it well:

> " In theory it's C talking to C, so it should be fast" - no. Not true.
> The main bit of Numpy that cimport numpy gives direct access to is
> just faster indexing of arrays. Numpy functions are called using the
> normal Python mechanism. They may ultimately be implemented in C, but
> that doesn't give a shortcut from Cython's point-of-view.

So this issue here is, calling this Numpy function requires translating the inputs back into python objects, passing them in, and then letting numpy do its thing.  I don't think this is the case for all Numpy functions (from timing experiments, some of them I call work quite fast), but plenty are not "Cythonized".